# Matching and return specific XML nodes

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery, flwor

I need to return all XML nodes whose ID attributes match between `<Settings></Settings>` and `<Profile></Profile>` and whose `<Setting/>` node has a `Value` attribute of `true`.
An example of my XML structure is found below:

`<HBDI>
        <Settings>
            <Setting ID="PreferenceCode" Visible="true"/>
            <Setting ID="SequenceCode" Visible="true"/>
            <Setting ID="QuadrantScores" Visible="false"/>
            <Setting ID="AdjectivePairs" Visible="false"/>
            <Setting ID="ModeScores" Visible="true"/>
            <Setting ID="Graph" Visible="true"/>
        </Settings>
        <Profile>
            <PreferenceCode ID="PreferenceCode">3332</PreferenceCode>
            <SequenceCode ID="SequenceCode">DCAB</SequenceCode>
            <Graph ID="Graph">Graph.jpg</Graph>
            <QuadrantScores ID="QuadrantScores">
                <QuadrantScore Name="A" Value="3" />
                <QuadrantScore Name="B" Value="3" />
                <QuadrantScore Name="C" Value="23" />
                <QuadrantScore Name="D" Value="46" />
            </QuadrantScores>
            <AdjectivePairs ID="AdjectivePairs">
                <AdjectivePair Name="A" Value="4" />
                <AdjectivePair Name="B" Value="7" />
                <AdjectivePair Name="C" Value="9" />
                <AdjectivePair Name="D" Value="10" />
            </AdjectivePairs>
            <ModeScores ID="ModeScores">
                <ModeScore Name="Lt" Value="34" />
                <ModeScore Name="Rt" Value="54" />
                <ModeScore Name="Upr" Value="3" />
                <ModeScore Name="Lwr" Value="24" />
            </ModeScores>
        </Profile>
    </HBDI>`

So what I want to achieve is to retrieve the following xml:

`<HBDI>
        <PreferenceCode ID="PreferenceCode">3332</PreferenceCode>
        <SequenceCode ID="SequenceCode">DCAB</SequenceCode>
        <Graph ID="Graph">Graph.jpg</Graph>
        <ModeScores ID="ModeScores">
            <ModeScore Name="Lt" Value="34" />
            <ModeScore Name="Rt" Value="54" />
            <ModeScore Name="Upr" Value="3" />
            <ModeScore Name="Lwr" Value="24" />
        </ModeScores>
    </HBDI>`

So, in the case of `ID="PreferenceCode"`, it's corresponding `Visible` attribute in `<Settings/>` is `true`, thus it needs to be returned. I must admit that I have no idea on how to do the match-up between the IDs. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dealing with XML, use XQuery:

```
DECLARE @MyXML xml = '
<HBDI>
    <Settings>
        <Setting ID="PreferenceCode" Visible="true"/>
        <Setting ID="SequenceCode" Visible="true"/>
        <Setting ID="QuadrantScores" Visible="false"/>
        <Setting ID="AdjectivePairs" Visible="false"/>
        <Setting ID="ModeScores" Visible="true"/>
        <Setting ID="Graph" Visible="true"/>
    </Settings>
    <Profile>
        <PreferenceCode ID="PreferenceCode">3332</PreferenceCode>
        <SequenceCode ID="SequenceCode">DCAB</SequenceCode>
        <Graph ID="Graph">Graph.jpg</Graph>
        <QuadrantScores ID="QuadrantScores">
            <QuadrantScore Name="A" Value="3" />
            <QuadrantScore Name="B" Value="3" />
            <QuadrantScore Name="C" Value="23" />
            <QuadrantScore Name="D" Value="46" />
        </QuadrantScores>
        <AdjectivePairs ID="AdjectivePairs">
            <AdjectivePair Name="A" Value="4" />
            <AdjectivePair Name="B" Value="7" />
            <AdjectivePair Name="C" Value="9" />
            <AdjectivePair Name="D" Value="10" />
        </AdjectivePairs>
        <ModeScores ID="ModeScores">
            <ModeScore Name="Lt" Value="34" />
            <ModeScore Name="Rt" Value="54" />
            <ModeScore Name="Upr" Value="3" />
            <ModeScore Name="Lwr" Value="24" />
        </ModeScores>
    </Profile>
</HBDI>'

SELECT      @MyXML.query('
<HDBI> {
    let $settings := /HBDI/Settings
    for $element in /HBDI/Profile/*
        where $settings/Setting[@ID = local-name($element) and @Visible = "true"]
        return $element
} </HDBI>
')
```

The XQuery loops through each child node of the `<Profile>` tag and check if it's set to `@Visible = "true"` in the `<Settings>` node. `local-name()` gives the name of the current node.